# Godaddy Delayed Email Service

Tags: php, smtp, shared-hosting

I have godaddy's economy hosting based on linux cpanel. I have created an email address as `info@mydomai.com` and I send my contact form queries to that mentioned email using the php `mail` function. This works properly. But when I send emails from the mentioned address, it takes around 2 hours to be received on the target address.

How can this time be reduced? Is this a problem on godaddy's side?

Comment: This has to do with server setups, and most likely gocrappy itself.

Comment: How did you send the email from info@mydomain.com, through PHP or a mail client?

Comment: `mail($to,$subject,$message);`

Comment: @PraneethNidarshan using email client `outlook` configured on SMTP and POP3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the mail works properly with `mail($to,$subject,$message);`, I think you should contact Godaddy support team in regards to this issue but before that please double check your [Outlook settings](https://sg.godaddy.com/help/using-the-outlook-setup-tool-2612).

Check this GoDaddy community topic related to [Email Delayed](https://sg.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Email/Email-Delayed/m-p/8703#M849)